# Can't get content to show under section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow with CSS3 - A Css-only fullscreen background image slideshow" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="css3, css-only, fullscreen, background, slideshow, images, content" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <section id="page">
            <ul class="cb-slideshow">
                <li>
                    <span style="background: #009dff;">Image 01</span>
                    <div><h3>Colourity</h3></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="background: #003840;">Image 02</span>
                    <div><h3>Colourity</h3></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="background: #02A676;">Image 03</span>
                    <div><h3>Colourity</h3></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="background: #4FAAC9;">Image 04</span>
                    <div><h3>Colourity</h3></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="background: #FF5952;">Image 05</span>
                    <div><h3>Colourity</h3></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="background: #96D6D9;">Image 06</span>
                    <div><h3>Colourity</h3></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS is kind of long so I thought I'd paste it [here](http://pastebin.com/PHB5MgdH). This is what I'm trying to achieve. I want to be able to scroll down and add content *below* what you currently see [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/) (This is the demo of where I got the code). I've tried fiddling around with the CSS for hours and nothing has been able to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: It's much easier to debug your code if you use http://JSFiddle.net. I copied your code over here: http://jsfiddle.net/3yxUP/

Comment: So, when you say "add content below", do you mean that you want to add content below the text in large letters ('Colourity')? Do you want to use "Colourity" as like a header?

Comment: I mean like being able to scroll down and having more pictures and links and stuff like that. I sort of want it to be like a header. That takes up the full page when you see it. But you'll be able to scroll down and theres more content. @MjrKusanagi

Comment: Ok, so do you also want the background image to scroll up as well and eventually be outside the viewport?

Comment: Exactly. I want everything to scroll up and there would be other stuff underneath it. @MjrKusanagi

Comment: Ok, so, maybe a little bit like this: https://www.google.com/nexus/5/. Well, just the header part..

Comment: Actually something like this http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html I don;t want the header, but I want the whole "top" part to show up when it loads. Then there's other stuff under it. @MjrKusanagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish what you want is to change the *position* style of the *.cb-slideshow* class from *fixed* to *absolute*. So, that part of the CSS will look like:

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The next problem you will then have to worry about is how to make sure that your content doesn't sit on top of your background. One way to do that is to also position your content absolutely (`position: absolute`) and offset it from the top by 100% (`top: 100%;` or whatever value that matches the height of *.cb-slideshow*.).

```
html,body{
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content{
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I've updated the JSFiddle to demonstrate these ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/3yxUP/3/. There is some overlap between the background and the content, but I think that might just be an issue with the JSFiddle UI. To resolve this, you can just add `#content{padding-top:15px;}` or something like that..

EDIT: I see why there is some whitespace above the background - it's because the element you are using is a *ul* which is normally rendered as a list with some margin before (and after?). Anyway, to resolve that, I added:

```
ul{
    margin:0;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

You should consider reading more about these CSS styles and how they affect the rendering of your content. Anyway, the updated JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3yxUP/5/.

Comment: You've been such a great help. Thank you very much!